# Getting parse error in aspx page while trying to load dynamic name to asp:panel ID section

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

What I am trying:
Adding panel as dynamic and assigning asp:panel id name as dynamic name value.
Eg : id name as panel_1, panel_2, panel_3...

I am using for loop in aspx page.
So I trying to add id name as dynamic but I getting error like
Parse Error
Description - "An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately".
Parser error message - Panel_ is not a valid identifier.

Version : Microsoft dot net version 4.0.303, Asp.net version 4.8.9220.

How to fix this.
[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: Yo must escape special character (angle brackets) inside HTML sequences : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references